# Can I connect to a x11vnc session without having it being displayed on my PC's monitor?

Tags: vnc, window-manager, session

I have a desktop machine running Fedora 36 KDE. I set up `x11vnc` on it with a systemd service file. Whenever I connect to the desktop via realvnc on my mac, the monitor of the desktop also turns on and mirrors what I do over on realvnc. Is there a way to configure `x11vnc` to not behave this way?

systemd service file:

```bash
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -noxdamage -shared"
#ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
User=user
Group=user
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

1. I tried to remove the `User=` and `Group=`, but the service errors out:

```bash
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

If I simulate this by first `su root`, then running this command, it works (but I have no idea why it won't in the systemd service):

```bash
/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -noxdamage -shared
```

2. Then I changed the systemd `ExecStart` to run this instead with the `User=` and `Group=` commented out:

```bash
/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :1 -auth guess -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -noxdamage -shared
```

Still the same error:

```bash
(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I have ran out of ideas on what to do for now, any comment is appreciated!

EDIT:
I changed the systemd file into this and it worked, even though it still mirrors the vnc screen with my desktop monitor. I am thinking it has something to do with the `-display :0` setting.

```bash
[Unit]
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth /home/user/.Xauthority -rfbauth /home/user/.vnc/passwd -noxdamage -shared"
#ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
#User=user
#Group=user
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

EDIT1:
I changed the `-auth` option to be `$(find /var/run/sddm/ -type f)` as that is what I think it needs in order to log in to a user session. `User=` and `Group=` is still commented out because it would throw an error otherwise. Then changing the display number to be 1 still errored. What I do right now as a compromise is to turn off the monitor but leave the HDMI cable connected, so `x11vnc` still thinks there is a physical display :0. I might have to look into `x11vnc` headless set up.

Comment: Why not setup xrdp? That will allow you to take over the computer without the monitor turning on.

Comment: @LPChip I am not really trying to take over the current session. My use case is generally this: 1. log out of computer after done working. 2.  log in to my computer via vnc and vpn when I need it outside of home, a new session is okay.

Comment: That would actually be very easy with xrdp. You connect to it, it logs you in, you disconnect session. You are still logged in, but in status disconnected. Network shares and everything remain working. Once done, you reconnect, and log out.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that `x11vnc` is meant to control your physical desktop session, you have to configure x to output to a dummy display in order to trick`x11vnc` to think you are controlling a physical session. I did not want to do that. What I needed as essentially a headless vnc machine.

So I decided to `systemctl disable sddm`, then install `tigervnc-server` and use that instead.

Now I can use the TTY console on my desktop if I really need to, there is always ssh if vnc fails me.

Comment: While you can use other vnc server, x11vnc can also be attached to xvfb or alike. (IIRC it can be configured to start an xvfb as well but I have a set of scripts / service files that start it independently, so that when x11vnc crashes I won't lose everything.)